# How to supress keys caught by iron-a11y-keys

Tags: polymer

In Polymer 1.0, I'm using iron-a11y-keys to capture the enter event on a paper-textarea so that enter keys trigger a submission event.  However, after the event is captured, I'm seeing the newline character be applied to the next paper-textarea that I create, adding a superflous newline.

This didn't happen in Polymer 0.5 using the 0.5 analogous elements.

Is there any way to suppress the delegation of the keys caught by iron-a11y-keys?

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()`?

Comment: Yup, I just tried that and it didn't fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by calling .preventDefault() on the "keyboardEvent" which is buried in the "keys-pressed" event like this:

```
onEnter: function (keyspressed) {
      keyspressed.detail.keyboardEvent.preventDefault();
      //do stuff
    }
```

You can also get at it like this:

```
onEnter: function (keyspressed, detail) {
      detail.keyboardEvent.preventDefault();
      //do stuff
    }
```